# Need autentication for urllib.request with Stripe in Python

Tags: python, json, curl, stripe-payments, urllib

I am trying to make a request to the Stripe API (which is a payment API) to get a json response which the API gives. I tried the following code I found in a Python course, but as the API needs to authenticate to get the response, I don't know how can I add that data in the request.

Making it in a curl request will be like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions   -u pk_test_51LoUz3BgfM0E8ZiCV8UO79gw8zw7fhSgHUEAVj4wS7igs5D4kKiNsxXGeKQEUhorImNUiCxCNNtidwNkhFPUHP4i0060lsvsbw:   -d success_url="http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/success.html"   -d cancel_url="http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/nosuccess.html"   -d "line_items[0][price]"=price_1LvNRkBgfM0E8ZiCTSiaNvNL   -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 -d mode=subscription -d client_reference_id="123" -d customer_email="email@email.com" -d client_reference_id="tokenized" -d phone_number_collection["enabled"]=true
```

This will create a new checkout session in your stripe account and the response is a json with the info of the checkout session.

**The authorisation I use in the curl request is the '-u' value of the publishable_key followed by ':' which means no password is required**

But when I try to make this in Python I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pau/Desktop/bsnbl/Backend/borrar.py", line 17, in <module>
    respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

**Python code:**

```
import urllib.request
import json

# Debido a cambios en la libreria ahora se deben pasar algunos cabeceros html
paymentInfo = '-u pk_test_51LoUz3BgfM0E8ZiCV8UO79gw8zw7fhSgHUEAVj4wS7igs5D4kKiNsxXGeKQEUhorImNUiCxCNNtidwNkhFPUHP4i0060lsvsbw:   -d success_url="http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/success.html"   -d cancel_url="http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/nosuccess.html"   -d "line_items[0][price]"=price_1LvNRkBgfM0E8ZiCTSiaNvNL   -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 -d mode=subscription -d client_reference_id="123" -d customer_email="abrix07@gmail.com" -d client_reference_id="tokenized" -d phone_number_collection["enabled"]=true'
res = bytes(paymentInfo,'utf-8')
print(str(type(res))) 
request = urllib.request.Request(
    'https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions',
    data=res,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print('1. ',respuesta)
cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
print(cuerpo_respuesta)
#Procesamos la respuesta json
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))
print(json_respuesta)
```

**For asking the question I am using the publishable key of my Stripe account for security reasons, if you try the code with the publishable code it will ask you for the secret key, which I can't give through here. Sorry for the inconvenience**

Comment: Have you considered using the official Stripe Python library ([`stripe-python`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python))?

Comment: I can't believe. I found the curl method to use with stripe, not python. Thank you so much Jonathan!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`urllib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), you'll need to set `Authorization` header on your request to add the API key as per the Stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication).

```py
request = urllib.request.Request('https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions',
  data=res,
  headers={
    'Authorization: Bearer sk_xxx'
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Unauthorized,

Answer (score 0):

I found the Python API in this link:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python

By default it appears as curl but when you add lang=python you get the python API code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from requests import post


response = post(url='https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions', headers={
    'Authorization': 'bearer pk_test_51LoUz3BgfM0E8ZiCV8UO79gw8zw7fhSgHUEAVj4wS7igs5D4kKiNsxXGeKQEUhorImNUiCxCNNtidwNkhFPUHP4i0060lsvsbw',
}, data={
    'success_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/success.html',
    'cancel_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/nosuccess.html',
    'line_items[0][price]': 'price_1LvNRkBgfM0E8ZiCTSiaNvNL',
    'line_items[0][quantity]': 1,
    'mode': 'subscription',
    'client_reference_id': '123',
    'customer_email': 'abrix07@gmail.com',
    'phone_number_collection[enabled]': True
})

print(response)
print(response.json())
```

Also check, that your price is recurring

If you prefere use "urllib", you can use this code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

# Debido a cambios en la libreria ahora se deben pasar algunos cabeceros html

res = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'success_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/success.html',
    'cancel_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/nosuccess.html',
    'line_items[0][price]': 'price_1LvNRkBgfM0E8ZiCTSiaNvNL',
    'line_items[0][quantity]': 1,
    'mode': 'subscription',
    'client_reference_id': '123',
    'customer_email': 'abrix07@gmail.com',
    'phone_number_collection[enabled]': True
})

print(str(type(res)))
request = urllib.request.Request(
    'https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions',
    data=res.encode('ascii'),
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
        'Authorization': 'bearer pk_test_51LoUz3BgfM0E8ZiCV8UO79gw8zw7fhSgHUEAVj4wS7igs5D4kKiNsxXGeKQEUhorImNUiCxCNNtidwNkhFPUHP4i0060lsvsbw',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
)

respuesta = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print('1. ',respuesta)
cuerpo_respuesta = respuesta.read()
print(cuerpo_respuesta)
#Procesamos la respuesta json
json_respuesta = json.loads(cuerpo_respuesta.decode("utf-8"))
print(json_respuesta)
```